# What is the connection between the science of testing, and Dune's idea of unlimited testing scales?

Tags: dune

Dune presents the idea that testing scales should never have a maximum level - it should always be possible to get a higher score or go to a more difficult level.  There's one memorable scene where someone is training on the sword-fighting robot and keeps winning and raising the level, until it's extremely dangerous.

Did Herbert base this idea on a philosophical concept from the real world?

Comment: Since you're asking about real-world versions of this, rather than asking about the concept within the context of a work of fiction, I don't think this site is the right fit for the question.

Comment: If a SF book proposed a unique rocket design, would it be appropriate to ask whether that rocket design had ever been used in real life?  It seems to me that it would be.

Comment: If I changed the question to ask whether any other SF books ever advocated that idea, would the question be a better fit then?

Comment: [As this meta question clearly demonstrates](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/355/13941), questions about real-life science are not something it's reasonable to expect experts on speculative fiction to answer. In its current form (asking about whether this was *inspired by* something in real-life) it's on-topic because it's now asking about the fiction itself--but it's also a totally different question.

Comment: And no, asking whether any other SF book ever did something similar is not a good fit because answers will either be a single book (in which case every answer is equally right) or a list which can never be comprehensive. Neither of those kinds of answers are good for the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to find out? The title, the question, and the question John O edited it to, are all a little bit different, and I suspect none of them is *exactly* what you're truly wondering so there's a lot of confusion.

Comment: As far as I have read (God emperor) and remember, this appears only once and it doesn’t seem to be intentional or conceptual but just a lack of a threshold – which in turn also happens in real life …

Comment: The book you're talking about isn't even by Frank Herbert. It's *The Machine Crusade*, by Kevin J. Anderson and Frank's son, Brian Herbert, almost two decades after Frank's death. That almost certainly renders your question moot, even ignoring its other problems. As for what Brian Herbert and Kevin J. Anderson based that tidbit on, it's likely the same thing they based the rest of their books on; the fact that Anderson wanted to rape Frank Herbert's legacy for monetary gain but needed Brian along for the ride to even attempt to pass off his tripe as legitimate.

Comment: @JamesSheridan -- I think he may be thinking of the scene with Alia sparring with the sword droid in **Dune Messiah**; Paul deactivates it with a precisely thrown knife, and the following conversation ensues: [Alia] “And why do the damned things have that many lights if we’re not supposed to try for them?” “A Bene Gesserit should ask the reasoning behind an open-ended system?” Paul asked.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten that passage. It's definitely possible that's what the QA had in mind.

Comment: @JamesSheridan yes, the sword droid is the scene I meant.  I was wondering if that idea was more developed in the other books, or if it was inspired by (or went on to inspire) something else

Comment: Aside from other books in the *nuDune* franchise, I don't think it has inspired anything. It may have been inspired by Frank Herbert's notes; Brian Herbert and Kevin J. Anderson claim to have based their stories on those notes. I personally find this very difficult to believe, as Frank Herbert never would have written such tripe as the *nuDune* series, and there are absolutely no indications he intended the return of the thinking machines. The villains hinted at in the final chapter of *Chapterhouse: Dune* seem Tleilaxu in origin.

Answer (score 2):

[Computerized adaptive testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computerized_adaptive_testing) works like that, but the idea is probably older than computerized testing, as I've heard it many times in regard to oral exams in university as well as job interviews: keep asking harder questions and determine the skill of the examinee by considering at what point he/she starts having problems.

There is an old and well-known physical exercise equivalent as well: high jump competitions work exactly like that: there is no fixed limit for how high you can jump - you just keep raising the bar until nobody can clear it.

In any case, "unlimited" is a bit of an exaggeration, as there are always limits. A swordfighting robot will certainly be limited by its basic construction in how dangerous it can be. The difficulty level of exam questions is limited by how smart the person who invents them and judges answers is. In highjumping, even if you ignore limits imposed by human anatomy, if you leave the ground fast enough, you'd jump straight out of Earth's gravity field, in which case the question of how high you jumped becomes meaningless.

Comment: There are always limits, but at least from a mathematical standpoint it's possible to continue improving performance, achieving higher scores, without actually reaching or exceeding the limit.